# HEROKU react-router error Object is not a function

Tags: reactjs, heroku, react-router

After 20th of February 2021 all new release of all my apps on heroku led to

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
at react-router.js:45
at Object../node_modules/react-router/esm/react-router.js (react-router.js:117)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap af8ac54243eabf0c85f6:678)
at fn (bootstrap af8ac54243eabf0c85f6:88)
at Object../node_modules/react-router-dom/esm/react-router-dom.js (react-router-dom.js:1)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap af8ac54243eabf0c85f6:678)
at fn (bootstrap af8ac54243eabf0c85f6:88)
at Object../src/index.js (index.js:1)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap af8ac54243eabf0c85f6:678)
at fn (bootstrap af8ac54243eabf0c85f6:88)
```

I come across this error even on my oldest projects where I didn't change a thing. I use latest stable version of react-router (5.2.0)

Comment: Hi Nikita, you may want to add the React version, info on what you used to create the React app and your React-router code. The community here will have an easier time helping you, if you do.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the problem by updating node version from 8x to 14x and removing package-lock.json from gitignore